# Where in the lifecycle of an Activity is the right place to set up event handlers on Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin

Imagine an app which is just a few activities with buttons, pointing to one another. **Where in the lifecycle on an activity should I bind the click handlers and where should I remove them?**

I've found that sometimes my event handlers fire twice, mostly when I go back/forth between activites, but I'm not sure how to reproduce this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it in `OnCreate` and in `OnDestroy`. The reason why can be easily seen in the diagram below.

[image: Android Activity Lifecycle]

As you see `OnCreate` only gets called when an `Activity` is created, which seems to be a very good place to hook up events that are living throughout the entire life of the `Activity`. Then you can unhook them again when it is finishing in `OnDestroy`. Some `Android` specific events such as listening for geo location are best to hook up in `OnResume` and unhook in `OnPause` such that they won't live on when not needed.

Comment: Do they always have to be unhooked in `OnDestroy`? Doesn't the garbage collector take care of that? In which case should I explicitly unhook the handlers?

Comment: I have never personally seen a reason to unhook things in `OnDestroy` and I have not had problems, as long as the types I am using in the `Activity` are disposable.